# Formula for maximum difference between any two values in two columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I have two sets of data in columns D and E. Both of which are a date & time. Column B is the exit date & time and Column A is the entry date and time. 
What I would like to know is the largest gap between an exit date & time and the next entry date & time.

The kicker is that it must meet certain conditions in columns A and J - which are locations as text.

So far the formula looks like this:

```
=MAX(LARGE(IF((A1:A2000=H6)*(J1:J2000=B6),(D1:D2000-E1:E2000)),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&-1+COUNT(IF((A1:A2000=H6)*(J1:J2000=B6),(D1:D2000-E1:E2000))))))-LARGE(IF((A1:A2000=A6)*(J1:J2000=B6),(D1:D2000-E1:E2000)),ROW(INDIRECT("2:"&COUNT(IF((A1:A2000=H6)*(J1:J2000=B6),(D1:D2000-E1:E2000)))))))
```

Data in colums looks something like:

```
Col A     Col D             Col E               Col J

ABC       14/03/2017 10:17  14/03/2017 10:52    131
ABC       14/03/2017 10:17  14/03/2017 10:52    131
ABC       14/03/2017 14:15  14/03/2017 14:42    131
```

Apologies for formatting, can't get it right!
There are several more rows with data and different locations in A.

So ideally the formula would return `14/03/2017 14:15 - 14/03/2017 10:52 = 0.1409`

Comment: is this data in order of entry time?

Comment: Are you using this as an **array formula** ??

Comment: To answer questions - no, it is not in any particular order. I was trying to use an array formula, but Jeeped has solved the problem without need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it as a standard formula (i.e. non-CSE),

```
=TEXT(INDEX(D:D, AGGREGATE(14, 6, ROW(D2:INDEX(D:D, MATCH(1E+99, D:D)))/((A2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1E+99, E:E))=B6)*(J2:INDEX(J:J, MATCH(1E+99, E:E))=H6)), 1)), "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm")&" - "&
 TEXT(INDEX(E:E, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW(E2:INDEX(E:E, MATCH(1E+99, E:E)))/((A2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1E+99, E:E))=B6)*(J2:INDEX(J:J, MATCH(1E+99, E:E))=H6)), 1)), "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm")&" = "&
 TEXT(INDEX(D:D, AGGREGATE(14, 6, ROW(D2:INDEX(D:D, MATCH(1E+99, D:D)))/((A2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1E+99, E:E))=B6)*(J2:INDEX(J:J, MATCH(1E+99, E:E))=H6)), 1))-
  INDEX(E:E, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW(E2:INDEX(E:E, MATCH(1E+99, E:E)))/((A2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1E+99, E:E))=B6)*(J2:INDEX(J:J, MATCH(1E+99, E:E))=H6)), 1)), "0.0000")
```

Result as:

```
14/03/2017 14:15 - 14/03/2017 10:52 = 0.1410
```

[image]

Comment: Ha! I should have been clearer, I only needed to return 0.1410 - just wanted to show how I got there. But i think the whole thing is actually clearer and shows the longest gap.

This is totally awesome BTW and completely answers my question. 

Well done Jeeped.

Comment: Didn't flag this as solved - have now. Well done again.